# Existence of gradient

Tags: functional-analysis

Here's a wikipedia page for gradient:

> The gradient of f is defined as the unique vector field whose dot product with any vector v at each point x is the directional derivative of f along v.

I don't get this definition. So my question is :

> Specifically, what is the least condition of $f$ to make gradient uniquely well-defined?

Below, I illustrate how I understand this article.

Let $H$ be a hilbert space and $f:H\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be a function Gâteaux differentiable in any direction at $x$.

The wikipedia article states that the gradient $\triangledown f(p)$ is a vector field such that $<\triangledown f(p),v>=D_vf(p)$.

But this cannot happen since $D_\diamond f(p)$ is not linear. That is, it does not need to be $D_{x+y}f(p)\neq D_x f(p) + D_y f(p)$

However, if $f$ is assumed to be Frechet differentiable, then by Riesz representation theorem, there exists $y\in H$ such that $Df(p)(x)=<x,y>$. If we assume $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, the gradient can be well defined as $\triangledown f(p) = y$.

I wonder if Frechet differentiable condition is more than enough to make the gradient well-defined..

Thank you in advance :)